# Add custom value in session

Tags: sessions

How can I add value in drupal session. I am adding value using $_SESSION = 'my value', but once trying to print $_SESSION variable it return blank.

Comment: It has to be an array. Collins' answer looks right.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal bootstrap takes care of session_start for you, so you should be able to define sessions like...

```
$_SESSION['my_data'] = 'my value';
```

You can also add the following in settings.php to determine the life span of the session

```
ini_set('session.cache_expire',     200000);
```